# Statistics Question about the Probability of Absolute Values

Tags: probability, statistics, absolute-value

I was tutoring a student today and was given a question that stated the following:

Find $P(|z| > -0.29)$.

Seems simple enough. But this doesn't really make sense in concept. Firstly, absolute values always yield a positive result, so it wouldn't really make sense for this question. Would the answer simply be $1$?

And secondly, for standard questions where $P(|z|>a)$, is the formula simplfied just $P(z>a) + P(z<-a)$ for values of $a>0$? For this one, it wouldn't make sense to just say $P(z<0.29) + P(z>-0.29)$ because you can't just flip the sign on absolute values. It just doesn't make sense for an absolute value equation to have a negative on the other side of the inequality.

Tried finding a YouTube video or anything just searching "probability of absolute value" and found nothing. It's shocking such a simple concept found in the first statistics course you take doesn't have anything to click on with that prompt so that I can show my student a simpler example that makes more concrete sense.

Comment: All values of $|z| \geq 0 > -0.29$, hence the answer is $1$.

Comment: I think you need the notion random variables, where z is not a number, but a map from a probability space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$. In this setting $P(|z|>a)=P\{\omega\in\Omega:|z(\omega)|>a\}$. This requires a understanding to the definition, which doesn't show up much if you consider classical models like rolling  dices.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if this was a typo—say, either $P(z > -0.29)$ or $P(|z| > 0.29)$ or even $P(|z| < 0.29)$ was meant. Otherwise, as you and @wolf_pack_32 point out, the probability is perforce $1$. But maybe that was actually the point of the exercise: for the student to think carefully about what is being asked, and not simply to start calculating from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

The question "Find $P(|z| > -0.29)$"  has the obviously correct answer of $1$.  It is likely either that it was a test of obviousness, or that it was asked in error.

As to your other question related to $P(|z|>a) = P(z>a)+P(z<-a)$, that expression is only correct when the events $z>a$ and $z<-a$ are mutually exclusive, as they are in this case when $a\ge 0$ but not necessarily when $a<0$.

More generally $P(A \cup B)=P(A) +P(B)-P(A \cap B)$ using inclusion-exclusion. So here you would have for general $a$:

$$P(|z|>a)=P((z>a) \cup (z<-a)) = P(z>a)+P(z<-a) - P(a < z < -a)$$

and thus for $a \ge 0$ you have $P(a < z < -a)=0$ giving $$P(|z|>a) = P(z>a)+P(z<-a),$$

while for $a \lt 0$ you have $P(a < z < -a)$ $=1 - P(z \le a) - P(z \ge -a) $ $= 1 - (1- P(z>a))+(1-P(z<-a)) = P(z>a)+P(z<-a)-1$ giving $$P(|z|>a) = 1.$$